# prevent onDocumentMouseDown when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I made a small application where the user can draw.
He can toggle drawing by pressing the corresponding button.

The problem is when drawing is enabled and I want to press the button again to disable it I draw behind the button, this because I start my drawing with the "onDocumentMouseDown" function.

This function is also called when I press the button.
Is there a way to control or fix this?

```js
var button = document.getElementById( 'draw' );
button.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function ( event ) {this.toggleDrawing();}.bind(this), false );
button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {this.toggleDrawing();}.bind(this), false );
```

In "toggleDrawing" I change the bool for drawing to false or true.
But like I said, pressing this button also causes my program to draw.

```js
onDocumentMouseDown(event)
{
  switch(event.button)
  {
    case 0:
      if(this.canDraw)
      {
        this.startPos = new THREE.Vector3(event.clientX, event.clientY,0);
        this.endPos = new THREE.Vector3(event.clientX, event.clientY,0);
        this.startLine();
      }
    break;
    default:
    break;
  }
}
```

So how do I click a button and call the function of this button without executing onDocumentMouseDown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little difficult to understand, but I think you want to not trigger a `mousedown` event that is registered on the `document` when you click inside the `button`.

If so, register a `mousedown` handler on the button that stops propagation of that event.

```
button.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) { 
  event.stopPropagation() 
}, false);
```

Otherwise, you could simply exit the drawing function early if the `event.target` is the `draw` button.

```
onDocumentMouseDown(event)
{
  if (event.target.id === "draw")
    return;

  // your code
}
```

---

Unrelated side note, instead of `.bind()` on an anonymous function, you can call it on the method itself, assuming it doesn't mind receiving the `event` object.

```
button.addEventListener('click', this.toggleDrawing.bind(this), false);
```

or just use an arrow function.

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleDrawing(), false);
```

Comment: I tested both options and they work fine, thank you :)